# combine results from two queries in aws cloud watch insight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am trying to query my log in aws cloud watch and have a case where i would like to combine logs from different places and display them properly.
i have two queries:

**Query1:**

```
fields @timestamp, RunId, Object, System1Duration 
| filter RunId = "ID1" AND ispresent(System1Duration)
```

**Result:**

```
RunID      |   System1Duration   
------------------------------
ID1        |    12               
------------------------------
```

**Query2:**

```
fields @timestamp, RunId, Object, System2Duration 
| filter RunId = "ID1" AND ispresent(System2Duration)
```

**Result:**

```
RunID      |   System2Duration   
------------------------------
ID1        |    12               
------------------------------
```

Each of these two queries give me the result I want, but I would like to get the result from both queries in one rwo, something like this Result:

```
RunID      |   System1Duration   |      System2Duration
-------------------------------------------------------
ID1        |    12               |        14
-------------------------------------------------------
```

my loggers log the result of each system duration seperately. unfortunately it won't be possible to log everything in one place at the moment, and I need to rely on aws cloudwatch Insight to get the proper insight